Reading data from a CSV file does not give me the correct output
I am trying to read some records from a CSV file. There are some characters prepended to the first records file column data.
Python code:
import csv
with open('test.csv','r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in spamreader:
        print(row)

CSV file content:
SO 5/4-3
DO 7015/2-1

There is only one column in the CSV file. Just copying the file above contents and changing the file extension to .csv should be enough to reproduce the issue.
Output:
['ï»¿SO 5/4-3']
['DO 7015/2-1']


did you check the file encoding?
